# Using both Ebean and JPA in the same Play Framework project

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework, ebean

I am trying to integrate Play Authenticate whilst still using JPA anywhere else in the app.

I got :

```
ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.OneToMany.orphanRemoval()Z
  at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi$JPAApiProvider.<init>(DefaultJPAApi.java:39)
  at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi$JPAApiProvider.class(DefaultJPAApi.java:34)
  while locating play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi$JPAApiProvider
  while locating play.db.jpa.JPAApi
    for parameter 2 at controllers.Persons.<init>(Persons.java:33)
  while locating controllers.Persons
    for parameter 5 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:48)
  while locating router.Routes
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router
    for parameter 0 at play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.<init>(HttpRequestHandler.scala:200)
  while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler
  while locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler
    for parameter 4 at play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:221)
  at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:221)
  while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
  while locating play.api.Application

1 error
```

before adding this line to build.sbt and plugins.sbt:

```
excludeDependencies += "javax.persistence" % "persistence-api"
```

however, I need that for my models as

```
[NullPointerException: null]
```

is triggered by @Entity annotations.

I have just started with Java with this Play Framework so there might be things I am missing out. Please point them out if necessary.

Comment: You have one version of the JPA API jar in the classpath (JPA 1?) and you need JPA API v2+. So Play or EBean are imposing some dependencies on you, and which JPA provider you can use

Answer (score 2):

There was this [thread](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/issues/270) where a guy asked to implement Hibernate into the project.

[This is his implementation](https://github.com/skelt/play-authenticate-hibernate)

Have a look at those links, it might help because then you don't have to use Ebean at all.